# Watchkit "The extension took too much time to initialize" Crash:"LAUNCH_HANG Exception"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I am stuck at a point, there is a crash in WatchKit Extension and I looked around in internet but failed to find the reason or any help to fix it.

As per the crash log it says

> The extension took too much time to initialize

Watch App is designed for Watch OS1, and I think the user is running the app in Watch OS2, after spending hours in debugging and time profiling now I can't analyze more. even I am not able to reproduce this again  ......

I also tried time profiling through instruments in **low memory** constrain but no clue in method call or system library.

[image]

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];

if (context!=nil)
{
    NSString *contextString = (NSString *)context ;

    if ([contextString isEqualToString:@"fromHomeScreen"])
    {
        isFromHomeScreen = YES;
    }
    else
        isFromHomeScreen = NO;
}

NSLog(@"[iWatch]Performance Logs: Main class app First method %@",[NSDate date]);

[self.welcomeLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome", @"")];
[self.tipsLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"To control speakers with your watch, set up Wireless Audio Multiroom on your mobile.", @"")];

 }

- (void)willActivate {
[super willActivate];
[self setTitle:@""];
[self configureWelcomeForFirstLaunch];}

- (void)configureWelcomeForFirstLaunch {
[self setNotificationObserverForName:kVDWearableSpeakerNoMusic object:nil selector:@selector(checkAndDisplayNextScreenFromWelcomeScreen) observer:self];
[self setNotificationObserverForName:kVDWearableInitialSetupCompleted object:nil selector:@selector(showTipsScreenAfterInitialSetupFinished) observer:self];
[self setNotificationObserverForName:kVDWearableSpeakerCurrentFunctionChanged object:nil selector:@selector(handleOtherSourcesCase) observer:self];
[self setNotificationObserverForName:kVDWearableSpeakerDataUpdated object:nil selector:@selector(UpdateScreenWithCurrentNotification) observer:self];




NSUserDefaults *tempDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:kVDSharedAppGroup];
NSArray *speakerArray =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[tempDefault objectForKey:kVDGetWearableSpeakerData]];
NSDictionary *requst = @{@"firstLaunchStatus":@"currentPlaying", };

NSLog(@"will activate called");
[VDWelcomeInterfaceController openParentApplication:requst reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"replyInfo=%@",replyInfo);

    NSLog(@"replyBlockCalled");
    if (replyInfo!=nil) {

        NSLog(@"gor valid reply without error");
        if ([speakerArray count]  > 0)
        {
            if(([replyInfo objectForKey:@"firstLaunchStatus"]) )
            {
                VDWearableSpeakerData *noMusicDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[tempDefault objectForKey:kVDGetWearableSpeakerDataNoMusic]];

                VDWearableSpeakerData *speakerData =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[tempDefault objectForKey:kVDGetWearableSelectedSpeakerData]];


                if ([speakerData.speakerType isEqualToString:@"Phone speaker"] )
                {
                    return ;
                }
                if (speakerData.currentFunction.integerValue !=0) {
                    [VDWelcomeInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"HomeInterface", @"VolumeInterface", @"SpeakerInterface"] contexts:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"noMusic"]];
                }

               else  if ([noMusicDict.noMusic boolValue])
                {
                    // [VDInitialInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"VDTipsInterface"] contexts:nil];
                    [VDWelcomeInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"HomeInterface", @"VolumeInterface", @"SpeakerInterface"] contexts:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"noMusic"]];

                    NSLog(@"1");
                }
                else
                {
                    // [VDInitialInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"HomeInterface", @"VolumeInterface", @"SpeakerInterface"] contexts:nil];
                    [VDWelcomeInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"HomeInterface", @"VolumeInterface", @"SpeakerInterface"] contexts:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"music"]];

                    NSLog(@"2");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}];
```

}

Any clarity on this exception and its handling would be much appreciated.

> Crash Log: Incident Identifier: 5C977759-3AE7-4701-A414-E4E7A27DB34E
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2   Path:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/93509EEB-9945-45CD-9DBD-60E5D1717F4A/Multiroom2-Phone.app/PlugIns/MultiRoom
>   WatchKit Extension.appex/MultiRoom WatchKit Extension Identifier:
>   com.samsung.MultiRoom.watchkitextension Version:             3167
>   (3167) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:
>   launchd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDmNk.jpg)
>       Date/Time:           2015-10-27 17:30:02.02 +0100 Launch Time:         2015-10-27 17:29:57.57 +0100 OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
>   Report Version:      105
>       Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Subtype: LAUNCH_HANG Exception Message: The extension took too much time to
>   initialize Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  0
>       Thread 0 name: Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019a8e0a40 mach_msg_trap + 8 (syscall_sw.h:105) 1
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019a8e08bc mach_msg + 72
>   (mach_msg.c:103) 2   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185484108
>   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2345) 3   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000185481e0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1032 (CFRunLoop.c:727) 4
>   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001853b0ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814) 5   Foundation                     0x00000001863292bc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
>   (NSRunLoop.m:367) 6   Foundation
>   0x000000018637e8f4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:388)
>   7   libxpc.dylib                   0x000000019aa00dac _xpc_objc_main +
>   660 (main.m:177) 8   libxpc.dylib                   0x000000019aa02ae0
>   xpc_main + 200 (init.c:1369) 9   Foundation
>   0x00000001864fb194 service_connection_handler + 0
>   (NSXPCListener.m:129) 10  PlugInKit
>   0x000000019376ecc4 -[PKService run] + 544 (PKService.m:104) 11 
>   WatchKit                       0x000000018b7250c0 main + 872
>   (main.m:55) 12  libdyld.dylib                 0x000000019a7de8b8 start
>   + 4 (start_glue.s:80)
>       Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019a8fbb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000019a9c1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1930) 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000019a9c1020 start_wqthread + 4
>   (pthread_asm.s:191)
>       Thread 2 name: Thread 2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019a8fc4fc kevent_qos + 8 1   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000019a7c0a04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232 (source.c:2545) 2
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x000000019a7af874
>   _dispatch_source_invoke + 0 (source.c:777)
>       Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019a8fbb6c __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000019a9c1530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284 (pthread.c:1930) 2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000019a9c1020 start_wqthread + 4
>   (pthread_asm.s:191)
>       Thread 4:
>       Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
>       x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x0000000007000806   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000c00
>       x4: 0x0000000000002507   x5: 0x00000000ffffffff   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000000b0
>       x8: 0x00000000fffffbbf   x9: 0x0000000007000000  x10: 0x0000000007000100  x11: 0x00000000fff0bdc0    x12: 0x0000000000000001
>   x13: 0x0000050000000603  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15:
>   0x0000060000000600    x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0x0000000000000000
>   x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000    x20:
>   0x00000000ffffffff  x21: 0x0000000000002507  x22: 0x0000000000000c00 
>   x23: 0x000000016fdfaaf8    x24: 0x0000000007000806  x25:
>   0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000007000806  x27: 0x0000000000000c00
>   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fdfaa00   lr:
>   0x000000019a8e08bc
>       sp: 0x000000016fdfa9b0   pc: 0x000000019a8e0a40 cpsr: 0x60000000

Any clarity on this exception and its handling would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the error, but have you tried moving your initialisation code - [self configureWelcomeForFirstLaunch] - into awakeWithContext? The Apple docs steer you away from initialising anything other than last minute UI changes in willActivate.

Comment: Are you sure you're not sitting in a breakpoint on application start?  Applications start a timer that expect you to finish any initialization by 10 seconds, else it crashes you.